# Unknown named module: 'react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, shoutem

I create a new React Native project and install @shoutem/ui in project  and include the Examples component of Shoutem UI into  React Native app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Examples } from '@shoutem/ui';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Examples />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', () => HelloWorld);
```

But when I run start the project , I get "Unknown  named module: 'react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin'" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug seems to be inside the `@shoutem/animation` module, in the `Parallax.js` file: https://github.com/shoutem/animation/blob/develop/Parallax.js
`NativeMethodsMixin` is not imported correctly from `react`:

If you change this:
`import NativeMethodsMixin from 'react/lib/NativeMethodsMixin';`
to this: `import NativeMethodsMixin from 'react';`
your app should work.

I would either file a Github issue on the `@shoutem/animation` project or check if the way `NativeMethodsMixin` is imported is specific to an older version of `react` and then use that version in your app.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed as of [v0.8.9](https://github.com/shoutem/animation/releases/tag/v0.8.9) release of [@shoutem/animation](https://github.com/shoutem/animation).